# Google chart not displaying ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

Not sure why but the title is displaying correctly for the chart but the PieChart is not displaying and I am not getting any errors.

Here a image of the results I am currently getting.

[image]

I have a feeling it something did wrong in the Index.cshtml file listed below.

Index.cshtml

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var chartData;

    //google.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Home/GetBarChartSalesAndExpenses",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {

                var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                dt.addColumn('string', 'Name');
                dt.addColumn('date', 'EnabledTime');   

                $.each(r, function (i, obj) {
                    var label = obj[0];
                    console.log(label);
                    //var value = new Date(parseInt(obj[1].MyDateTime));
                    //var value = new Date(parseInt(obj[1].substr(9)));
                    var value = new Date(parseInt(obj[1].replace('/Date(', '')));

                    dt.addRow([obj[0], new Date(parseInt(obj[1].replace('/Date(', '')))]);
                });

                console.log(dt);

                var options = {
                    title: "hello",

                };

                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart($("#chart")[0]);
                chart.draw(dt, options);

            },
            error: function (r) {
                console.log(r);
                alert("Error loading Post and Comment data! Please try again.");
            }
        });

    }
</script>


<div id="chart" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

This is where I am getting the data to populate the chart and everything is working correctly here.

HomeController

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public JsonResult GetBarChartSalesAndExpenses()
    {

        List<Website> Sales = db.Websites.ToList();

        var chartData = new object[Sales.Count];

        int j = 0;

        foreach (var i in Sales)
        {      
            chartData[j] = new object[] { i.Name, i.EnabledTime};
            j++;
        }

        return Json(chartData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Any thoughts? Many thanks.

Comment: What does your browser console tell you?

Comment: It empty I just try using BarChart it working! but not sure why PieChart is not working it this case

Comment: Does the Network tab showing it making the call to `/Home/GetBarChartSalesAndExpenses`? Does that return json data?

Comment: check the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format) for the pie chart. the column types accepted are string and number, date is not included...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that a pie chart only works if the data column type is numeric (https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format).

In your case the data type is a time. Bar charts can work with time as the data type (https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#data-format)